# Asterisk: create user with template via AMI

Tags: javascript, asterisk, asteriskami

I need to modify sip.conf with AMI, adding a new user to it. Everything works fine, and I can create a user like this without problems:

```
[1000]
secret=pass12
```

But I have to create user with template like

```
[1000](mytemp)
secret=pass12
```

and I don't know how to do this. Neither Google, nor Digium forum can't help me.
P.S. I use JavaScript asterisk-manager to interact with Asterisk, and here is my code, which adds extension:

```
var amiAction = {
        action: 'UpdateConfig',
        reload: 'yes',
        srcfilename: 'sip.conf',
        dstfilename: 'sip.conf',
        'action-000000': 'newcat',
        'cat-000000': '1000',
        'action-000001': 'append',
        'cat-000001': '1000',
        'var-000001': 'secret',
        'value-000001': 'pass12'
    };

ami.action(amiAction, function(err, resp) {
    console.log(err, resp);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var amiAction = {
    action: 'UpdateConfig',
    reload: 'chan_sip',
    srcfilename: 'sip.conf',
    dstfilename: 'sip.conf',
    'action-000000': 'newcat',
    'cat-000000': '1000',
    'options-000000': 'inherit=template-name'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've tried this, but:

```
'cat-000000': '1000 [(mytemp)]',
```

... should work just fine.  If it does not, what error message does it throw?

Comment: It's not works. No error is throwing, but it creates a line like this: [1000 [(mytemp)]], not like [1000] (mytemp)