# Appending categories with template via AMI and PHP

Tags: php, asterisk, asteriskami

I'm using a PHP library to update config files of asterisk.

I add a user like this:

```
$a->write('Action: updateconfig\r\nReload: yes\r\nSrcfilename: users.conf\r\nDstfilename: users.conf\r\nAction-000000: NewCat\r\nCat-000000:test\r\nAction-000001: append\r\nCat-000001: test\r\nVar-000001: mailbox\r\nValue-000001: test\r\n ...etc user fields');
```

But also I have a template `templatename` so I want to add categories with template. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149360/asterisk-create-user-with-template-via-ami), where is talled that you need simply change category name to `test [(templatename)]`. But this simply doesn't create anything.

If you need I can post library but it's just custom library with sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You should use quoted string if you sending something like that.

Also it is highly NOT recommended use users.conf in case if you are not guru.

Reason: it can result not what you expect/insecure sections.

Use sip.conf or iax2.conf.